# Fast way of Selecting Indices from Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a large array, `X`, out of which I must select interesting `indices`, as below. X is `60000 x 784`. I'm wasting about a second running this at every call during a loop.

```
%timeit subX = X[:,indices]
890 ms ± 23.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

How can I access my array faster? indices is a `list` and can range from 500 numbers to 784.

Comment: Changing the array order to F order might help

Comment: @busybear can you please elaborate?

Comment: In F order, the array is stored in memory with the first axis as contiguous data. Since you are accessing the entire first axis (column), it may be more efficient to have the data stored in this fashion--so it's not jumping around the memory space to retrieve data. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues) will give a more thorough explanation. Not sure how much (or if) you'll get a performance boost with this though. Worth trying.

Comment: @busybear just tried it. Down to 230ms!

Comment: Nice! That's a decent boost. You do have a lot of data so it's going to be hard to avoid having some slow down.

Comment: did you test `np.take(a, indices)`?